# What is wrong with this lua coding?

Tags: lua

I'm coding and I am getting an error in here:

```
Ammo = 450
Rocket = 20
Money = 35041
--Can I attend this mission?
function attendMission()
    if Ammo >= 400 or Rocket >= 35 and Money >= 30000 then
        return Money = Money - 30000
        Msg("Attending Mission\n")
        Msg("You now have "..Money.." dollars\n")
    else
        Msg("You do not have the resources to attend this mission\n")
    end
end
print(attendMission())
--Ammo Amount
function whatIsAmmo()
    if Ammo > 0 then
        print("You have "..Ammo.." Ammo")
    else
        Msg("You have no Ammo")
    end
end
print(whatIsAmmo())
 --Rocket Amount
function whatIsRocket()
    if Rocket > 0 then
        Msg("You have "..Rocket.." rockets")
    else 
        Msg("You have no rockets")
    end
end
print(whatIsRocket())
--Money Amount
function whatIsMoney()
    if Money > 100000 then
        Msg("You have "..Money.." dollars, wow your rich!")
    elseif Money > 0 then
        Msg("You have "..Money.." dollars")
    else
        Msg("You have no money")
    end
end
print(whatIsMoney())
```

It says there is an end expected near =. I've been searching for a while but I do not know how to fix it. I have narrowed down that the error is in this section though:

```
function attendMission()
    if Ammo >= 400 or Rocket >= 35 and Money >= 30000 then
        return Money = Money - 30000
        Msg("Attending Mission\n")
        Msg("You now have "..Money.." dollars\n")
    else
        Msg("You do not have the resources to attend this mission\n")
    end
end
```

Comment: In Lua (unlike in C and some other languages), an assignment is a statement, not an expression.

Comment: Okay, I did that but I am now getting "'end' expected (to close 'if' at line 6) near 'Msg'"

Comment: `return` also needs to be the last statement in a block (at least in lua 5.1). So that has to be the last line in the block. Though you can use `do return end` to force a block to make it work.

Comment: You also don't even NEED the `return`. `Money = Money - 30000` will suffice.

Comment: @EtanReisner: Whether `return` is *required* to be at the end or not, having statements immediately after a `return` doesn't make sense. They'll never be executed.

Comment: @KeithThompson That's certainly true (though occasionally useful for debugging) but my point was about the cause of the syntax error specifically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found out what the issue was. Apparently moving back some words to create:

```
Ammo = 450
Rocket = 20
Money = 35041
--Can I attend this mission?
function attendMission()
if Ammo >= 400 or Rocket >= 35 and Money >= 30000 then
    Msg("Attending Mission\nYou now have "..Money.." dollars\n")
    Money = Money - 30000
else
    Msg("You do not have the resources to attend this mission\n")
end
end
print(attendMission())
--Ammo Amount
function whatIsAmmo()
if Ammo > 0 then
    print("You have "..Ammo.." Ammo")
else
    Msg("You have no Ammo")
end
end
print(whatIsAmmo())
 --Rocket Amount
function whatIsRocket()
if Rocket > 0 then
    Msg("You have "..Rocket.." rockets")
else 
    Msg("You have no rockets")
end
end
print(whatIsRocket())
--Money Amount
function whatIsMoney()
if Money > 100000 then
    Msg("You have "..Money.." dollars, wow your rich!")
elseif Money > 0 then
    Msg("You have "..Money.." dollars")
else
    Msg("You have no money")
end
end
print(whatIsMoney())
```

Like this worked out perfectly. But, thank you guys for helping me out! Especially your comment Josh, who taught me something new ;)